# i keep getting an error message saying 'Navbar' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> 'Navbar' is declared but its value is never read

In app.js the code is :

```
import React from 'react';

import Navbar from './components/navbar';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';

function App() {

  return (

    <>

    <Router>

      <navbar/>

      <switch>

        <Route path ='/' exact/>

      </switch>

    </Router>

      
    </>

  );

}


export default App;
```

In navbar.js the code is

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import { link } from 'react-router-dom';


function Navbar()

 {

  return (

    <>

        <nav className='navbar'>

            <div className='navbar-container'>

            <link  to='/' className='navbar-logo'>

              BLKA
            </link>
            </div>
            
        </nav>

    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: All your React components should start with a capital letter when they're defined and when rendering them. `<navbar> --> <Navbar>` and also `<switch> --> <Switch>`. The capital letter is how it knows what's a react component, and what's a vanilla HTML element

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.